# Setting the default subtitles

Tags: ffmpeg, audio, encoding, subtitles, .srt

I managed to create the subtitle file, using different language with one single FFMPEG command:

```
ffmpeg -y -loglevel "repeat+info" 
-i "file:Intervista.mp4" 
-i "file:Intervista_fr.srt" 
-i "file:Intervista_en.srt" 
-i "file:Intervista_it.srt" 
-c copy 
-map 0 -dn -map "-0:s" -map "-0:d"  
-map "1:0" "-metadata:s:s:0" "language=FR" "-metadata:s:s:0" "handler_name=French"  "-metadata:s:s:0" "title=French" 
-map "2:0" "-metadata:s:s:1" "language=ENG" "-metadata:s:s:1" "handler_name=English" "-metadata:s:s:1" "title=English" 
-map "3:0" "-metadata:s:s:2" "language=ITA" "-metadata:s:s:2" "handler_name=Italiano"  "-metadata:s:s:2" "title=Italiano" 
"file:output.mp4"
```

For some reason, the default subtitles shown when I start the video is English, which is the one in the middle. How do I set the default subtitle file to Italian?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `-disposition` [option](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Main-options) :

`-disposition:s:0 0 -disposition:s:1 0` to clear the disposition for first and second subtitles (fr and eng).